# How are interfaces represented at a lower/assembly level?

Tags: object, assembly, interface, linker, compiler-construction

I understand objects are just chunks of data, where the first member variable starts at the exact same location as the object. For example, an object whose pointer points to location 0x0100, will also have the first member variable located at 0x0100.

But how do interfaces in a language like Java, which have no implementation, work? These are purely abstract types.

As in, how does a CPU or compiler know to interpret Object A as Interface X, or Object B as Interface X and Y depending on the context? Is this something done at the compiler level, that has no bearing on the lower level interpretations?

Comment: Read about vtables.

Comment: Java compiles to Java bytecode, not machine code. Java bytecode is a rather high level representation compared to machine code and the Java VM interpreting it does in fact know what interfaces each object implements.

Comment: In C++ for example, yes, the object layout and so on is known at compile time.  Given a pointer to an object with no virtual member functions, there's no info about its type.  I think a Java interface is like a purely virtual base class in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that in languages like Java & C#, the first member of an instance is a pointer to a class-shared object; this object participates in identifying the actual class that was instantiated, in checking down casts, in determining the overrides to call for virtual method invocations, and in determining the implementation to use for interface method invocations.

> But how do interfaces in a language like Java, which have no implementation, work? These are purely abstract types.

Sure interfaces themselves are "abstract", but the interface methods are always invoked on instances of concrete classes (that implement the interfaces), so that's where implementation comes in.

The language treats interfaces, similar to classes (both abstract and concrete), assigning their methods to indexes, and using those method indexes in lookup (at the class-shared object of the instance) to find the actual implementation to invoke.

So, key is that the interface methods are given positions in the array of method references within the class-shared object of each instantiable type (that implements the interface), such that each class could have a different implementation of an interface method.

Comment: Thank you! Those last 3 paragraphs explained it very well. However, what is a "class-shared object"? Is this the .obj file, the actual object in memory, or something else?

Comment: It is an object in memory, structure of some sort (it either contains or references an array), but not necessarily a true Java or C# Object, as it can be internal to the runtime implementation. It is like a vtable in C++, a low-level internal construct not advertised to the programmer, so its implementation can vary as needed (e.g. for versioning of the language over time, or for different implementers of the same language).  Each class that can have instances has one of these, so when we do `new X (...)`, that object for class `X` is referred to by the instance in that hidden first field.

Answer (score 0):

Let be the interface

```
interface A {
  void hello();
  void hello2();
}
```

We can immediately define the function with the interface as a parameter

```
void function example (i A) {
    i.hello();
    i.hello2();
}
```

What exactly will be compiled here?
Interface function calls.
And how is this possible?
It is possible because an interface type variable contains as many pointers to functions as there are functions defined within the interface.
Interface in short is a structure that contains pointer variables to functions.

Now any class that implements the interface can be assigned to it. With this allocation, pointer variables to functions (of the interface) are "filled" with the addresses of the functions located in the vmtable (of the class).

This means that an interface variable always sees the functions defined in it and only them (unless casted to the class)

----------------------------------
So for example if a class implements the interface.

```
class B implements A {
  public int justAField;

  @Override
  public void hello() {
    System.out.println("Hi.");
  }
  
  @Override
  public void hello2() {
    System.out.println("Hi2.");

  public void anotherMethod() {
    System.out.println("Another one.");
  }
}
```

We can have

```
example(new B())
```

The calls `i.hello(); i.hello2();` trigger the corresponding functions of the class

Comment: Usually there's a level of indirection, e.g. what C++ would call a vtable, so you don't need a whole set of function pointers for every object of a type that implements an interface.  Each object has its members and a pointer to its table of methods for that interface, so the size of each object doesn't scale with the number of methods defined in the interface.  (Unless I'm wrong about that, and it's different from how normal C++ implementations do polymorphism.)

Comment: It's exactly as you say in terms of an object instance But I am talking about the interface itself and how it is represented in assebly-machine code. Usually it already exists, and in fact it can be used directly (within a function in which the interface is passed as a parameter and within this function its functions can be called). `i.hello(); i.hello2();` (We have no idea which class implements the i interface) In order to be able to do this (i.e. compile), the interface need some kind of structure of its own, to refer to the virtual methods of the class(at runtime)

Comment: Those are member functions so they're called on a specific object `i` that implements that interface, though.  The member functions get a `this` pointer through which they can access fields of the object, whether or not any of the interface methods actually do that.  So the arg to `void function example (i A)` can't *just* be a pointer to the vtable, it has to be a pointer to an instance of the object which has fields and a vtable, doesn't it?  So that reference to the object can be passed as the `this` arg when calling `i.hello()`.

Comment: --> These statements (calls of the 2 functions) at compile time, assume the existence of 2 variable memory locations (pointers to functions).
Otherwise, compilation cannot be done.
--> At runtime, what you say happens.
These variables refer (with the help of "this") to the constant offsets of the virtual functions of the class that implements the interface.
    At a second time could exist a completely different class that implements the interface.
To be completely independent of the classes, those have this mechanism
You are thinking in C++ logic which has no interfaces